# How to split column and make count for over limit values

Tags: python

I'm new in python language. I tried to load a text file, to split columns and count for over limit values for many rows such as the following:

```
Box Type    Serial Nb   Sensor Type Line Name   Point Nb    Point Index Segd Code   Set Grid Easting    Set Grid Northing   Surface Elevation   Resistance(ohm) Noise (µV)  Leakage(Mo) Tilt (%)    Latest Update   
FDU-428 12263085    1   4619    1169    1   2   566443.8    3456742.2   8.0 132.23  5.78    5.0 -1.33   Sat Dec 15 12:52:17 AST 2018    
FDU-428 5848688 1   4589    1170    1   2   565641.6    3455415.0   7.4 133.2   4.99    5.0 -1.29   Sat Dec 15 12:52:17 AST 2018    
FDU-428 12318634    1   4619    1168    1   2   566401.8    3456769.2   7.5 132.3   6.26    5.0 -0.33   Sat Dec 15 12:52:17 AST 2018    
FDU-428 12280956    1   4589    1164    1   2   565390.0    3455578.5   7.4 133.46  7.85    5.0 -0.96   Sat Dec 15 12:52:17 AST 2018    
FDU-428 11271012    1   4607    1180    1   2   566551.1    3455897.5   7.1 132.8   5.81    5.0 -0.36   Sat Dec 15 12:52:17 AST 2018    
FDU-428 12245682    1   4661    1337    2   2   574607.9    3453890.8   6.7 133.32  4.14    5.0 -1.19   Sat Dec 15 12:52:17 AST 2018
```

these value for geophone abnormal specification 10 =Resistance(ohm),11=Noise (µV),12=Leakage(Mo) ,13=Tilt (%) , i work as qc for seismic survey exploration

My code is like the following:

```
myfile = open('aaa.txt','r')
myvar=(myfile.read())

rows = (myvar.split('\n'))
for i in range(1,len(rows)):
    if float(rows[i].split('   ')[10]) > 140:
        print (rows[i].split('   ')[10])
```

and I met this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "D:/Python/python/import_text2.py", line 11, in <module>
    if float(rows[i].split('   ')[10]) > 140:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: from your example, which value(s) you want to compare to 140?

Comment: Your `for i...` loop is iterating over single letters.

Comment: _Can anyone help me please?_ Help you with what specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A pure Python proposal

Your for loop is iterating of letters, I guess it's not what you want.

You can try this instead:

```
text_file = "aaa.txt"

with open(text_file,'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

threshold = 140

for row in data.split('\n'):
    # by default, the .split() method use the 
    # white space (any amount) as the separator.
    for word in row.split():
        try:
            if int(word) > threshold:
                print("{} is greater than {}".format(word, threshold))
        except:
            print("Cannot convert word to number.")
            pass
```

Here, we check the numerical value against the threshold.
If you want to check for the string length instead, you can modify the code on your own, it will be a good exercise, but in your data sample you don't have such cases.

Comment: thank you for answer me , in my file i try to split column and focus on [10,11,12,13], and give the count for abnormal value ,[10]>140,[11]>20,[12]<5 and [13]>2.5 or -2.5.                                  regards

Comment: for example , i need count [10] abnormal = the count of abnormal and percentage and etc...

Comment: What exactly are `[10,11,12,13]`? Do these numbers correspond to precise columns?

Comment: these value for geophone abnormal specification 10 =Resistance(ohm),11=Noise (µV),12=Leakage(Mo) ,13=Tilt (%)  , i work as qc for seismic survey exploration

Comment: You should definitely add these precision to your main post for the other to understand your question more accurately. ;-) Actually, what is the initial separator in your file? A fix amount of spaces? A tabulation? Others?

Comment: Based on your data, you have much more columns than values... We cannot guess the mapping between the two. Please provide data with a fully comprehensive separator.

Comment: The file have spaces between each characters but not symmetrical space, i try to define the string as float characters to be define such as :  [1] = 12263085 , [2]= 1 , etc.... and first character no need it , thank you for help me and this is first time use python , i try to used it for our work beside our software plus QGIS software.

Comment: The problem with spaces is that you also have spaces **in** the column names **and** in the values as well. So you cannot differentiate if a space is a normal character or a column separator. You'd better have to figure out how to have *better* input data. This may probably be fixed during data exportation if they were exported from a field device for example.